# How to add additional <li> in jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to build an autocomplete jQuery autocomplete.
And I want to add an additional  `<li>`
 at the end of the list.
So I used this:

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  
  
  jQuery.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = function( ul, items    ) {

        var that = this;
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });
       $( ul ).append("<li class='selectall'>show all</li>");
       
       $( ".selectall" ).on( "click", function() {
       console.log("select!");
          $( ".label" ).css("color", "red");
        } );
       
    };
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label class="label" for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

That works fine except the error message that appears in the console when I hover over the additional `<li>`.
Maybe that's  because every `<li>` has a value and a key except my additional `<li>`.
But I don't know how to avoid that error message.

I also tried this: [Add a additional <li> tag to the end of rails3-jquery-autocomplete plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092893/add-a-additional-li-tag-to-the-end-of-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-plugin)

But it's just the same.

Comment: If you inspect your `<li>` from the drop down you will see that the li tag contains a `<div>` element too, try to add that div element too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `_renderMenu` is executed before `_renderItem`, so 
you can add new item in `_renderMenu` and render it in `_renderItem`.

```
$.widget( "custom.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu : function( ul, items            ) {

        var that = this;
        items.push({label:"show all", value:"", isShowAll:true})
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        });

    },
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var li = $( "<li>" )
            .attr( "data-value", item.value )
            .append( item.label )
            .appendTo( ul );

        if(item.isShowAll===true){
            li.on( "click", function() {
                console.log("ShowAll selected");

            });
        }
        return li;
    }    
});
```

> Note: I am using `$.widget` instead of prototype, but I guess the result should be the same.

Comment: Tried it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvsjnn7w/6/ but it didn't works @Marinos An

Comment: It is because you did not set correctly (as on your original post) the prototype property: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvsjnn7w/8/